# UWP: The default HorizontalAlignment is Left not Stretch

Tags: uwp

The documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment says that the default `HorizontalAlignment` is `Stretch`.

But trying it in a new dummy app, it looks to be Left. The designer confirms it's Left too:

[image]

Here's the versions I'm targetting (these are the default values, I didn't set them):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UWP: The default HorizontalAlignment is Left not Stretch

Your screenshot shows Button's layout property, and `HorizontalAlignment = left` is default value for Button, you could find the default button style in **generic.xaml** file, and I will paste it below.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ButtonRevealStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPadding}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>

                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>

                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right. I forgot about the generic style which sets the default values.